# Add additional "aud" entry to Azure ADB2C token

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using a custom policy in Azure ADB2C to authenticate and authorize users to my API backend. This works fine.

Now I want to add an additional "aud" entry to the Azure ADB2C jwt token such that I can use the same token for a different service which expects this aud entry to be present.

Right now Azure ADB2C fills in the "aud" field with the ApplicationID for which it was created.

Is there a way to add a static entry to the "aud" field in Azure ADB2C?

Comment: Do you mean you expect the same token to access multiple services?

Comment: @CarlZhao: yes, I want to use the same token to access multiple services.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, I think you are expecting to use the same token to access multiple services (please correct me if my understanding is wrong). Unfortunately, you cannot do this.

A token can only correspond to one `scope`. The access token is issued according to the [api audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) you want to access, and it is unique! A token can only have one `audience`, and you cannot use multiple scopes to request access tokens. If you need to access other services, you should obtain a token for each service separately.

---

**Update**：

You can put multiple apis of the same type in the scope because they are still of the same type in essence. But it is not acceptable to request the same access token for two different types of APIs.

test1：

[image]

test2：

[image]

Comment: Unsure if I understand correctly, but from the link you've sent: "scp": "The set of scopes exposed by your application for which the client application has requested (and received) consent. Your app should verify that these scopes are valid ones exposed by your app, and make authorization decisions based on the value of these scopes." I understand from this that there can be multiple scopes defined.

Comment: It also says that the type of "scp" is "String, a space separated list of scopes". So I guess that makes it clear that there can be multiple scopes in one token.

Comment: @Copiltembel  This is related to your api type. If you are using the same api, you can put multiple scopes. For example, if you use `ms graph api`, you can put `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`,`https://graph.microsoft.com/Policy.Read.All`... in the scope, but it is still essentially It is the same api.

Comment: No, I am using a different API. Do you mean that it is not possible with Azure ADB2C, or with any jwt provider? There are some interesting articles on the topic: https://www.pingidentity.com/en/company/blog/posts/2019/oauth2-access-token-multiple-resources-usage-strategies.html and https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/oauth2-access-token-usage-strategies-for-multiple-resources-apis-part-2-304bab2570a9

Comment: @Copiltembel However, if you put different kinds of apis into the same scope, it will only obtain tokens for the first api in order, that is, the `aud` claim of the access token will only have one api, the first api.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the problem. Since I cannot add anything to the "aud" field, the only workaround that I see is to validate against the same aud in all the APIs.

Comment: @Copiltembel  I just used the auth code flow to test, and it is true that I cannot put different types of apis in the `scope`.

Comment: @Copiltembel  I will update the answer and put in my test results.